# How to make a textbox value equal the number 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I have a bit of jquery code. What I want to do is hide the textbox but make the value in the textbox equal the number 1. The textbox does hide but it does not make the textbox value equal "1". How is it suppose to be written?

Code is below:

```
if (clickedNumber === 'Yes or No') {

$('#answerYes').show();
$('#answerNo').show();
$('#na').show();
$('#numberAnswerTxt').val() == '1';
$('#numberAnswerTxt').hide();

}
```

"#numberAnswerTxt" is the id of the textbox.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#numberAnswerTxt').val(1)
                     .hide();
```

Comment: Hi, that was a fast reply, sorry I could not connect to server so had to wait until it connected me, by the way this has worked, Thank You

Answer (score 1):

`$('#numberAnswerTxt').val() == '1';` should change to `$('#numberAnswerTxt').val('1');`

Double equals is a conditional by the way, if you want to set a variable then use a single equals sign.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/val

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#numberAnswerTxt').val('1');
```